# Slackbot always showing active

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

We are developing a bot using howdyai BotKit. Here, the problem is when I kill the server, the bot is still in active mode. But no command is working. When I check processes using

```
  ps -ef | grep node
```

No process is running with node. But it is still in active mode. Any help, why it is in active mode?.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the app settings for which you were asking.

- Choose your application [here](https://api.slack.com/apps). Login if needed.
- Go to `Bot Users` in side menu.
- Toggle `Always Show My Bot as Online` button.
- Now your bot should go offline when you turn off RTM api.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I could not see *Bot users* in side menu.

Comment: I have created bot user while creating app. Maybe you haven't created bot user. Then that option would be hiding somewhere.

Comment: I have changed bot user option, still it is showing as *active* always.

Answer (score 0):

That RTM toggle is only for events api based bot btw. If you use any recent starter kit, it will by default steer you to events api functionality, and this "always on" switch in the slack api settings is off by default.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I couldn't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please explain clearly.

Comment: There are a few different ways to integrate with Slack's API. If you are using the RTM Api. your server status will show if the light is lit. If you are using Events API, you can superficially set the online status in slack settings: https://api.slack.com/apps/YOURBOT/bots 

You should check if this is toggled if your bot is showing online even though your server may be down.